# Reevaluate dependencies of a while loop

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand how while loops work in tensorflow. In particular I have a variable, x say, that I update in the while loop, and then I have some values that depends on x, but when running the while loop the values does not seem to be updated when x changes.

The following code where I have tried to implement a simple gradient decent optimizer might illustrate what I mean:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=4, dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
y = tf.multiply(x,x)

grad = tf.gradients(y, x)

def update_g():
    with tf.control_dependencies(grad):
        return tf.identity(grad[0])

iterations = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
g = tf.Variable(initial_value=grad[0], dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)
c = lambda i_loop, x_loop, g_loop: i_loop < iterations
b = lambda i_loop, x_loop, g_loop: [i_loop+1, tf.assign(x, x_loop - 10*g_loop), update_g()]
l = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i, x, g], back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res_g = sess.run(grad)
    res_l = sess.run(l, feed_dict={iterations: 10})
    res_x = sess.run(x)


print(res_g)
print(res_l)
print(res_x)
```

Running this on tensorflow 1.0 gives this result for me:

```
[8.0]
[10, -796.0, 8.0]
-796.0
```

and the issue is that the value of the gradient is not updated as x changes.

I have tried various variations on the above code, but can not seem to find a version that works. Basically my question is if the above can be made to work, or do I need to rethink the approach.

(Maybe I should add that I am not interested in writing a gradient decent optimizer, I just built this to have something simple and understandable to work with.)

Answer (score 2):

With some help from the other answer I managed to get this working. Posting the complete code here as a second answer:

```
x = tf.constant(4, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.multiply(x,x)

grad = tf.gradients(y, x)

def loop_grad(x_loop):
    y2 = tf.multiply(x_loop, x_loop)
    return tf.gradients(y2, x_loop)[0]

iterations = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
i = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
c = lambda i_loop, x_loop: i_loop < iterations
b = lambda i_loop, x_loop: [i_loop+1, x_loop - 0.1*loop_grad(x_loop)]
l = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i, x], back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=1)

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.05)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res_g = sess.run(grad)
    res_l = sess.run(l, feed_dict={iterations: 100000})
    res_x = sess.run(x)


print(res_g)
print(res_l)
print(res_x)
```

changing the learning rate from the code in the question and increasing the number of iterations gives the output:

```
[8.0]
[100000, 5.1315068e-38]
4.0
```

Which seems to be working. It runs reasonably fast even with high iteration count, so there does not seem to be something really horrible going on with updating the graph in each iteration of the while loop, a fear of which probably was one reason why I didn't opt for this approach from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Having `tf.Variable` objects as loop variables for while loops is not supported, and will behave in weird nondeterministic ways. Always use `tf.assign` and friends to update the value of a `tf.Variable`.

Comment: I guess you are refering to the use of `g` in the loop, since I do use `tf.assign` for `x`, or might having `x` as a non-variable help?

I have tried a version without `g` at all earlier, and just doing `tf.assign(x, x_loop - 10*grad[0])`. I also just now tried moving the `update_g` function down, and changing the return to `return tf.assign(g, grad[0])`. In both cases I get the same result.

Comment: Even though you use tf.assign on x inside the while loop you have x as a loop variable. This will create weird inconsistencies in the runtime. I recommend not having x as a Variable or not having x as a loop variable.